# React & Ant Design: показывать номера строк в Textarea

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, textarea, ant-design

подскажите, можно ли сделать так, чтобы компонент Input.Textarea фреймворка Ant Design показывал бы номера строк

соответственно:

1. при прокрутке текста прокручивались бы и номера строк
2. при переносе текста на новую строку номер строки для перенесённой части не ставился бы

   ```
    [1] строка 1
    [2] очень длинная строка
    [] которая автоматически была перенесена
    [] на другую строку
    [3] опять короткая строка
    [4] и еще короткая
    [5] и еще одна строка
   ```

, т.е. если есть 10 строк, то и чисел будет 1..10, если же из-за wrap и ширины textarea длинные строки переносятся, то для них всё равно только один индекс - в общем поведение обычного текстового редактора, например Nodepad++

Comment: _при переносе текста на новую строку номер строки для перенесённой части не ставился бы_ - а что тогда должны показывать номера строк, если не каждая строка будет учитываться?

Comment: @Grundy, ничего, пустое место - `[1][2][][][3][4][5]`, т.е. если есть 10 строк, то и чисел будет 1..10, если же из-за wrap и ширины textarea длинные строки переносятся, то для них всё равно только один индекс - в общем поведение обычного текстового редактора, например Nodepad++

Comment: Стоит добавить это пояснение в вопрос. Сейчас в вопросе непонятно, почему одни переносы учитываются, а другие нет

Comment: судя по всему в ant design такого нет и надо будет руками все делать

Comment: @Grundy, да, Ant Design такую возможность "из коробки" не представляет к сожалению, поэтому и интересовало - можно ли как-то модифицировать  `Input.Textarea`, есть сторонник компоненты, но не хотелось бы ими захламлять проект, если есть возможность получить нужный функционал малыми переделками. Основных проблем тут 2 - если делать через `::before` или через соседний `<div>` - 1) как мотать номера одновременно с перемоткой текста 2) как оставлять пустые строки. Как вариант думал рядом поставить еще один Textarea и связать перемотку первого и второго, но как и не костыль ли это

Comment: Почему использование готового решения называется захламлением, а копипаст исходников для повторения функциональности - не называется?

Comment: Если это делается условно 10 строчками кода, то почему бы и не написать?
существующие же решения зачастую добавляют излишний функционал и тяжеловесны
Если же требуется существенная переработка - то тут вопросов нет, нужен готовый компонент

Comment: [пример](https://phuoc.ng/collection/mirror-a-text-area/display-the-line-numbers-in-a-text-area/) - не совсем 10, разбираться все равно придется